# Beginner question on Excel regarding Time not showing properly

Tags: excel, formatting

Pivot table not showing what I want to show. Its a total amt of time in a day by every person included in the list. I formatted all values to [h]:mm:ss including the data and pivot table and yet it shows 0:00:00. Do I need to include some codes in here or just make the right formatting?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have posted. I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then **EDIT** your question to make it possible for others to help you.

Comment: It confuses me, but I already solve this. Apparently, it didn't read the input as "Time" even though I format every cell to time many times over. so i had to delete that column and retype all the data and repeat the formatting. thankyou by the way

Comment: Probably the cell contents were Text and not Number.  Changing the format of such a cell will not convert the text representation to the number. There are easier ways than retyping everything **after** you formatted the cell, but glad you have it working.